# Add Footer to Angular Material Datepicker

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I am trying to implement a "Today" button on the Angular Material datepicker, but it must be positioned after the content.

[image]

After reading the [API](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/api), it seems that, while it is straight-forward to customize the header of the datepicker by adding `[calendarHeaderComponent]="myComponent"`, there are no options to add or customize a footer.

I am currently trying to make it work on top of the custom header example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3xdhb1?file=src/app/datepicker-custom-header-example.ts

Also, it seems that in [this issue](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/11753), a similar feature is proposed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Above answers does not say that after adding extra elements to **DatePicker** or **DateRangePicker** using `renderer2` and `appendChild()`, it won't allow for **appropriate keyboard accessibility** since extra added elements won't get focus as they should. The focus is trapped inside `mat-calendar`, which uses the **`cdkTrapFocus`**.

[image]

Since **@angular-material v11.2.12** there is possibility to customize **[Confirmation Action Buttons](https://v11.material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#confirmation-action-buttons)**. Due to this, it is no longer needed the usage of `renderer2` and `appendChild()` in order to customize footer.

Together with **[Confirmation Action Buttons](https://v11.material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#confirmation-action-buttons)** and **[Customizing the calendar header](https://v11.material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#customizing-the-calendar-header)** it is possible to add extra buttons, labels, texts etc. to header and the footer.

Here is the **[example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jqavef?file=src/app/date-range/date-range.component.html)**, both with edited footer and header.

Answer (score 2):

With newer Angular versions it's a built-in feature. Just use the [mat-datepicker-actions](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#confirmation-action-buttons) ditective. [Live example](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/examples#datepicker-actions)

Comment: I wish i saw this earlier...

Answer (score 0):

At my work we did something like that to add a timepicker to the datePicker. You can add the button by using `.appendChild()` or `.append()`.

The idea is to append a component into the datepicker is I remember well. I'm not good enough in angular to reproduce it correctly but here [is a basic repro of the concept on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c9xqse?file=src/app/datepicker-overview-example.ts)

Also, i found [enter link description here](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/dynamically-add-components-to-the-dom-with-angular-71b0cb535286) that seems accurate for your needs.

Hope it helps !

Comment: Seems like while this works, I would prefer doing it in a cleaner way. I will keep the question open for now.

Comment: @AlbertoRivera I am pretty sure there is not clean way to modify an external component. If you find something let me know i'm interested :)

Comment: Accepting this answer, as it was the guideline for my actual implementation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using **mat-datepicker-actions**

```
<input class="form-control " title="Data" matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" formControlName="date">
          <mat-datepicker-toggle class=" my-auto" matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
          <mat-datepicker #picker>
            <mat-datepicker-actions class="">
              <button title="today" class="btn button" (click)="setTodayDate()" matDateRangePickerApply>
                [Hoje]
              </button>
            </mat-datepicker-actions>
          </mat-datepicker>
```

[result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61fG6.png)