# Adjust MatDateRangeActions to work both with native selection and custom ranges

Tags: angular, angular-material, datepicker

I'm implementing a datepicker using @angular/material MatDateRangePicker. Users should be able to select date ranges as well as to use some custom date range presets ("Last X days" buttons).

As far as I know there are two ways of implementing this: 1) create custom Header component (as described [here](https://www.qupaya.com/blog/date-range-picker-custom-ranges)); 2) use MatDateRangePickerActions buttons (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61683747/add-footer-to-angular-material-datepicker), for example). I'd really love to use the second option as letting users to confirm their manual selection (via Apply button) seems a good idea especially when a server request fires on the datepcker value change and we want to handle only users' wanted selections.

So I have this in my template (just prototyping):

```
<mat-date-range-picker #picker>
   <mat-date-range-picker-actions>
     <button matButton (click)="getRangePreset(picker, 7)">last 7 days</button>
     <button mat-button matDatepickerCancel>Cancel</button>
     <button mat-raised-button color="primary" matDatepickerApply>Apply</button>
   </mat-date-range-picker-actions>
</mat-date-range-picker>
```

And a `getRangePreset` method looks something like this:

```
getRangePreset(
    picker: MatDateRangePicker<Date>,
    rangePreset: number,
  ): void {
    const currentDate = new Date();
    const rangeDate = new Date();
    rangeDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() - rangePreset);
    picker.select(rangeDate);
    picker.select(currentDate);
    picker.close();
  }
```

The problem is that I cannot make it work with Apply action button. I must me missing something, but the `MatDateRangePicker.select()` method sets the value in the datepicker *without updating the view* (this is the state before calling `picker.close()`:

[image]

I cannot understand why it works that way. If I close a datepicker and then open again, selection is painted in the view. Does it mean I need some kind of a force re-render just after the call to .select()?..

If Apply button is clicked in this state of view, the datepicker is closed but *inputs also get cleared*. So it seems the only way to proceed with selected range is to close datepicker programmatically ignoring Apply (the last line of code above).

On the other hand, when I select a date range manually, clicking dates, then, of course, view changes, but not the model, as the component "waits" for a user to confirm changes via Apply button.

I've really been struggling a lot to get the same behaviour with custom range preset: i.e. select dates *only in the view* and apply value changes via confirmation button.

Is there a way to do it? How I need to change `getRangePreset` method or the template to have the same behaviour for both cases? Any suggestions (including alternative solutions if there's a better way to do it) are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
getRangePreset(picker: MatDateRangePicker<Date>, rangePreset: number):{
const currentDate = new Date();
const rangeDate = new Date();
rangeDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() - rangePreset);
picker.select(rangeDate);
picker.select(currentDate);
picker._applyPendingSelection();
picker.close();
```

}`

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn’t seem to change anything: the calendar’s view is left untacked with _applyPendingSelection.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I've finally come up with.

I used a custom header component to display the calendar action buttons (*Apply*, *Cancel* positioned via css) and date range presets buttons. The component is passed as an input to `mat-date-range-picker` like this:

```
<mat-date-range-picker #picker [calendarHeaderComponent]="DateRangeHeaderComponent">
  <mat-date-range-picker-actions>
    <div class="custom-css-class-to-position-buttons-under-the-calendar">
    <!-- here comes the content of presets located in DateRangeHeaderComponent -->
    </div>
  </mat-date-range-picker-actions>
</mat-date-range-picker>
```

In the constructor of `DateRangeHeaderComponent` we have access both to the datepicker (data binding part) this header is associated with and to the calendar instance (UI part):

```
constructor(
  private calendar: MatCalendar<Date>,
  private picker: MatDateRangePicker<Date>,
) {}
```

So we can manage the selection in the calendar via `this.calendar.selected = new DateRange(start, end)` (where `start` & `end` are calculated values corresponding to the range selected by a user via a preset button). And we can as well apply this range to the date model via `this.picker.select()` method and imitate the behaviour of the MatDateRangePicker's *Apply* action button like this:

```
const appliedRange = this.calendar.selected as DateRange<Date>;
const { start, end } = appliedRange;
this.picker.select(start);
this.picker.select(end);
this.picker.close();
```

Some additional logic was needed to distinguish between the selection made by a user manually and the selection with date range presets (e.g. 'Last 7 days'). In my case, I made use of the fact that MatDateRangePicker sets 00:00:00 time on manual selection, while selection by a preset must have a non-zero time part. This is not probably the 100% reliable way, but it's sufficient enough for the product business needs (not to mention that I've tried some alternative solutions and failed to find an ideal one). Still, in both cases apply-selection logic works the same way – which is what I needed.